# Balance difference between different wallets with the same key(s)?

Tags: wallet, multibit

I have multiple USB sticks holding the same private key. All with multibit 0.5.9 on windows.

1 wallet is showing 2 cents more than all the others when I sync them all with the blockchain. How can that be?

Comment: 2¢ USD? or 2 bitcents?

Comment: Can you make your title more readable. The idea of a title is to be somehow connected to a problem being solved, thus facilitating later search on the subject. If everyone would use something like your title, the resource would be of no use.

Comment: What transactions have you done?  Probably you did a transaction using 1 of your wallets and it created a "change" address for you, the private key of which exists in that wallet only.  Some wallet software does not make it easy (or possible) to see your "change" addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the title... Someone has changed it.

2 Bitcents...

I use one of the wallets for transaction going in/out. That wallet is showing +2 cents on the others. The others I just sync from time to time.
Last address addition was some months prior to noticing the descrepancy.
All wallets were copied from the same starter wallet which is the one with the +2 cents.